# Pandas : How to iterate over only back dates over two ID columns to give unique IDs and count?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, time-series, iteration

I have a dataset which has data for over a month. I need to count the players who have played on the previous day. So if I am looking at date of 5th June users I need to find the number of users who were there in dates preceding 5th June even once.
Dataset is something like this:-

```
Day pid1    pid2
1   1a  1b
1   1c  2e
1   1d  2w
1   1e  2q
2   1f  4r
2   1g  5t
2   2e  7u
2   2w  8i
2   2q  9o
3   4r  0yu
3   5t  5t
3   6t  1w
4   1a  2e
4   1f  9o
4   7u  6h
5   8i  4f
5   9o  3d
5   0yu 5g
5   5t  6h
```

I have tried iterating over days then pid1 and pid2 but to no avail and it is computationally expensive as I have over 5 million data points.

I really do not know how to approach this and the only thing I have tried is this:-

```
for x in range(1, 31):
    for i in ids.iterrows():
        if i['Ids'] == zip(df4['pid1'], df['pid2']):
            print(x, i.count())
```

But it still doesn't let me iterate over only previous days and not next days.

I need answer that looks something like this (results are not accurate) but I need unique count of users of previous days on a given day:-

```
Day Previous day users
1   0
2   2
3   2
4   5
5   5
```

Comment: It means there were 3 users who were there in Day 1. For day 3, the number 5 means 5 users were there either on Day 1 and Day 2. For day 4 the number 7 means the user were there either Day 1, 2 or 3. You get the gist right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After op's comment, I am providing both answers:

Solution for checking only one day before:

Instead of using two for loops and one if statement I used more pandas operations to increase computational speed

```
df.head()


   Day  pid1 pid2
0   1   1a   1b
1   1   1c   2e
2   1   1d   2w
3   1   1e   2q
4   2   1f   4r
```

Then `groupby` `Day` to get players in list:

```
tmp = df.groupby("Day").agg(list)
tmp


Day  pid1                   pid2
1   [1a, 1c, 1d, 1e]        [1b, 2e, 2w, 2q]
2   [1f, 1g, 2e, 2w, 2q]    [4r, 5t, 7u, 8i, 9o]
3   [4r, 5t, 6t]            [0yu, 5t, 1w]
4   [1a, 1f, 7u]            [2e, 9o, 6h]
5   [8i, 9o, 0yu, 5t]       [4f, 3d, 5g, 6h]
```

Then `concat` ith day players and (i-1)th day players:

```
tmp2 = pd.DataFrame(tmp["pid1"] + tmp["pid2"], columns = ["current_day"])
tmp2["previous_day"] = tmp2.shift()
tmp2 = tmp2.fillna("nan")
tmp2

Day current_day                                 previous_day
1   [1a, 1c, 1d, 1e, 1b, 2e, 2w, 2q]            nan
2   [1f, 1g, 2e, 2w, 2q, 4r, 5t, 7u, 8i, 9o]    [1a, 1c, 1d, 1e, 1b, 2e, 2w, 2q]
3   [4r, 5t, 6t, 0yu, 5t, 1w]                   [1f, 1g, 2e, 2w, 2q, 4r, 5t, 7u, 8i, 9o]
4   [1a, 1f, 7u, 2e, 9o, 6h]                    [4r, 5t, 6t, 0yu, 5t, 1w]
5   [8i, 9o, 0yu, 5t, 4f, 3d, 5g, 6h]           [1a, 1f, 7u, 2e, 9o, 6h]
```

And finally finding length of intersection of days that is number of players that played at the current day and previous day.

```
tmp2.apply(lambda x: len(list(set(x["current_day"]) & set(x["previous_day"]))), axis = 1)

Day
1    0
2    3
3    2
4    0
5    2
dtype: int64
```

Solution for checking all previous days:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for day_num in df["Day"].unique():
    tmp = df[df["Day"] == day_num]
    tmp2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([tmp["pid1"], tmp["pid2"]]).unique(), columns = ["players"])
    tmp2["day"] = day_num
    res = pd.concat([res, tmp2])
res = res.reset_index(drop = True)
```

This combines all `pid1` and `pid2` to `players`

```
res.head()

    players day
0   1a      1
1   1c      1
2   1d      1
3   1e      1
4   1b      1
```

Then calculating all previous day players for a current day:

```
result = []
for day_num in df["Day"].unique():
    current_players = pd.Series(res[res["day"] == day_num].players.unique())
    previous_players = pd.Series(res[res["day"] < day_num].players.unique())
    result.append(len(current_players[current_players.isin(previous_players)]))
result = pd.Series(result, index = df["Day"].unique())
result
```

The result in `pd.Series` format:

```
1    0
2    3
3    2
4    5
5    5
dtype: int64
```

Hope it works!

Comment: It gave right results for Day 1, 2 and 3 but for 4 it should be 5 instead of 0. I believe it's only checking with the previous day on the same row, the idea is great thanks I am trying to build on this. So what I want is previous day column goes on increasing in a cumulative manner.

Comment: Oh I thought the only previous day will be calculated. Tomorrow I will edit based on the correction.

Comment: I modified the answer according to your comment @abhas-mehrotra

Answer (score 2):

According to me you want to count the number of player Ids which has appeared on all days before the given Day. You can try the below:

```
m=(df.melt('Day').sort_values('Day').drop_duplicates(['Day','value'])
     .reset_index(drop=True).drop('variable',1))
m.assign(k=m.groupby('value').cumcount()).groupby('Day')['k'].sum() #assign it back
```

---

```
Day
1    0
2    3
3    2
4    6
5    7
```

If cumulative counts are not required instead 1 appearance per cumulative day is required, use:

```
m.assign(k=m.groupby('value').cumcount().ne(0)).groupby('Day')['k'].sum() #.astype(int)
```

---

```
Day
1    0
2    3
3    2
4    5
5    5
```

Comment: The answer for 5th day is 5 and for 4th day is 5. I think this is iterating over current day as well

Comment: @AbhasMehrotra can you take a look again? I did, and found these results correct. Also the expected output posted by you is wrong. Please dont do that. It takes away lot of time to match that

Comment: The player 6h didn't play until the 4th day so his count shouldn't be included right? So that would bring the count from 6 to 5.The players 4f, 3d, 5g didn't play till the 5th day so that count comes down to 5 again. I am sorry.

Comment: @AbhasMehrotra agreed on `6h` ,its not counted in my code, however, `2e` appears twice before the 4th day once on Day 2 and once on Day1 , so it should be counted as 2 in Day 4 right? if you count that as 1, i have added another code to use after you define `m` , please check and let me know